# Inecting NLOG in .Net core without a concrete <T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nlog

The [*docs*](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2) say that we should use this in order to have Nlog in .Net core DI:

```
.UseNLog();  // NLog: setup NLog for Dependency injection
```

And then we will be able to use DI:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

But we don't inject ILogger to every class we want to log within it.

We have a service called `IHelper` which in turn injects `Ilogger` :

```
public class Helpers : IHelpers
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Helpers(ILogger<Helpers> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

So it turns out that we always use `Helpers` as a type. ( :/)

I've tried to Inject only(!) `ILogger` (without a type) but I got an error.

**Question:**

Is there any better pattern for using `ILogger` without a dummy `<Helpers>` (in my case...) type? Or is there a way not to specify any type?

Comment: Creating an `ILogger<YourClass>` is essential for when it comes time and you need to analyze your log data.  If all logs are `ILogger<Helpers>` then you are causing yourself more pain,  because the whole point of having a logger instance for each class is to 1. know which classes are and aren't being used (telemetry) 2. assist in troubleshooting errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `IHelpers` and `Helpers` generic. This would allow you to use `ILoggerFactory` to create an instance of `ILogger` that uses a category that is the name of the type argument. Here's an example:

```
public interface IHelpers<T> { }

public class Helpers<T> : IHelpers<T>
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Helpers(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<T>();
    }
}
```

To use this in e.g. `SomeClass`, use `IHelpers<SomeClass>` for DI in the constructor:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly IHelpers<SomeClass> _helpers;

    public SomeClass(IHelpers<SomeClass> helpers)
    {
        _helpers = helpers;
    }
}
```

Lastly, register `IHelpers<T>` as an open generic, like this:

```
services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(IHelpers<>), typeof(Helpers<>)));
```